# Why are checkboxes not posted when unchecked?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I use a library which constructs a Javascript object from a form's elements : `$("#frm").serializeJSON()`

Here is [the website](https://medium.com/@mwakatumbula_/code-15ecdb18c2ef) of the library.

So at runtime when a checkbox is not checked then it does not appear inside the Javascript object constructed from `$("#frm").serializeJSON()`. Although I set a name attribute to the checkbox element. So why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide `checkboxUncheckedValue` property with suitable value for your case.

For example

```
$("#frm").serializeJSON({checkboxUncheckedValue: "false"})
```

Check the doc for more details https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON?tab=readme-ov-file#include-unchecked-checkboxes

Comment: by the way how did you find the github site you provided ?

Comment: Watching source code and googling jquery.serializejson.js after.
By the way, in the article you provided in question there is same information